# How do make Itext to Accept unicode having sequence like below

Tags: java, swing, javafx, itext

How do make Itext Library to accepts unicode as below. Actually it prints a hindi string using java console.But i am trying to accept it by itext in order to make a report.

```
u0915\u093e\u0930 \u092a\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0915\u093f\u0902\u0917
```

Below are the code snipet which i am using

```
BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("/home/mani/Downloads/arialuni.ttf", 
    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,    BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font=new Font(unicode,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));
table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10, 60, 30 });
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CUSTOMERS",
    this.headerFont));
PdfPCell balanceLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
    "\u0915\u093e\u0930\u092a\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0915\u093f\u0902\u0917", font));
```

But again it didn't recognize text.
Expected :-कारपार्किंग

Comment: Itext didn't recognize this Unicode string .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want the output to look like the first line in this screen shot:

[image]

This screen shot was taken from the file [hindi.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hindi.pdf), created using the [HindiExample](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/fonts/HindiExample) example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Font f = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("\u0915\u093e\u0930 "
            + "\u092a\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0915\u093f\u0902\u0917", f);
    document.add(p1);
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("\\u0915 \u0915 \\u093e \u093e \\0930 \u0930\n"
            + "\\u092a \u092a \\u093e \u093e \\u0930 \u0930 \\u094d \u094d"
            + "\\u0915 \u0915 \\u093f \\u093f \u093f \\u0902 \u0902"
            + "\\u0917 \u0917", f);
    document.add(p2);
    document.close();
}
```

Your question isn't complete in the sense that you don't show us which font you are using (in my case `FONT` is `FreeSans.ttf`), nor which encoding (it should be `IDENTITY_H`).

**If you were expecting the first line of the screen shot,** my answer is twofold:

1. Use a font that knows how to render Hindi (e.g. FreeSans.ttf, arialuni.ttf,...),
2. Use the correct encoding (Identity-H).

Or maybe the problem was more trivial: you forgot a `\` character before the first `u`.

**If you were expecting something else,** then please look at the second and third line where I inserted the Unicode value and a space in front of every Unicode character. You will notice that every character is rendered correctly, *but* no ligatures are being made. If you need ligatures, you need to wait for the next major version of iText that will bring support for Hindi, but that support won't be available as open source software. (We noticed that too many developers are using iText without a commercial license, so we're going to offer some components as closed source only.)

**UPDATE:**

you have updated your question, but once again you didn't provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that allows people to *reproduce* the problem. When I complete your code, I get this result:

[image]

This is my code:

```
BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font=new Font(unicode,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10, 60, 30 });
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CUSTOMERS"));
PdfPCell balanceLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\u0915\u093e\u0930\u092a\u093e\u0930\u094d\u0915\u093f\u0902\u0917", font));
table.addCell(customerLblCell);
table.addCell(balanceLblCell);
table.completeRow();
table.setSpacingBefore(10);
document.add(table);
```

I have also updated the example online: [HindiExample](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/fonts/HindiExample)

What is missing in your code? You create a table with **3** columns and you create **2** cells. I don't see you adding the cells to the table anywhere, not do I see cell **3** anywhere. So even if you add the two cells to the table, they aren't going to be rendered because iText discards incomplete rows (unless you use the `completeRow()` method).

I use this font: [FreeSans.ttf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/blob/master/resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf) (you can download it [here](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf)). I've tried it with MS Arial Unicode (arialuni.ttf) too, this gives me the following result:

[image]

In short: your allegation that iText doesn't recognize that Unicode is wrong. There are ample examples that prove that the Unicode renders correctly (using FreeSans *and* MS Arial Unicode).

Comment: thanx sir for quick help. As i mentioned i will choose a newest version of itext as soon as it will be available .Meanwhile i am trying exactly same as you shown. But in mine case कारपार्किंग is not shown in pdfcell. Plz help me , above i mentioned mine code also.

Comment: i am creating font as   BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("/home/mani/Downloads/arialuni.ttf", 
           BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,    true);
           Font font=new Font(unicode,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));

Comment: If font is an issue then plz provide me downloading link too. I had already tried both font which those are mentioned in your example.Thnx in advanced!

Comment: Is your problem now that no text is shown, or that the text is incorrect (र as full character instead of diacritic, ि after क instead of before) ? If the former, you should revisit your code, as @BrunoLowagie has shown you exactly what you should do. If the latter, iText cannot help you for now.